# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function - ReactJS /GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Initially when I have the following code for the component , there are no errors at all

```
function Menu(props) {
 
  const { menuLinks } = props.data.site.siteMetadata;
  
  return (
<div></div>
  );
};

export default props => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            menuLinks {
              name
              link
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => <Menu data={data} />}
  />
);
```

But when I add `const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);` under the menuLinks constant it gives the error  as shown below

×
←→1 of 2 errors on the page

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
Menu
E:/path/src/components/Menu.js:5
  2 | import { graphql, StaticQuery, Link } from 'gatsby';
  3 | import Dropdown from './Dropdown'
  4 |  
> 5 | function Menu(props) {
  6 |  
  7 |   const { menuLinks } = props.data.site.siteMetadata;
  8 |   const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);
```

Any help to find a solution for this would be great!! Thanks

Comment: What is your React version?

Comment: react": "^16.5.1", @devserkan

Comment: Ok, please see the answer in the link above.

Comment: Awesome ( I m bit new to reactjs) thanks so much im gonna upgrade reactjs , looks like it will work - :) @devserkan

Comment: It worked!! thanks heaps @devserkan